# Left_Join on same tables in Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table and a class marked as `@Entity` with

```
 @Table(name="Employee")
```

It has two fields, Id and Name

i want to do left join on same table like,

```
Select t2.name, count(*)
from Employee t1 left join Employee t2 on t1.Id = t2.Id
where t1.Name = 'asd'
group by t2.Name
```

Comment: your query has no sense, but why left join? you can use simple inner join, besides why are you joining :S

Comment: Ok i figured out that left join and inner join are same on this. So consider inner join. I am doing it because i need some particular functionality which i will get by doing the above query :-). So i am asking how can i achieve it??.

Comment: Think about the following case,
Assume a situation like you have a table that has records of employees.


        `EmployeeName EmployeeID ManagerID performance`

Here Manager is in turn an employee so that ManagerID would be an EmployeeID. Let’s assume performance is int and holds values from 1 to 5

So if you are asked to list all the employees who fall under the manager whose performance is more than 4.



`Select e.EmployeeID
From Employee e join Employee m on e.ManagerID = m.EmployeeID
Where m.performance >= 4`

Comment: If is that the case you map in the entity class as a Self-join, is that what are you looking?

Comment: Yes thats what i am looking for. Could you please post an example model and criteria. It will be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a workaround, I converted that query into sub query

`Select EmployeeID From Employee
Where ManagerID in  (Select EmployeeID where performance >= 4 )`

And used DetachedCriteria and i got it worked. But this will reduce my performance. SO i will try your method and see if i can get it worked

Ref
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2389790